How do I put a button to the bottom of a box?
I have recently started using html in order to create a website for my project. I have planned on making this website that contains the intro page, that has a button, revealing further contents.
This is my current html code:


body {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #24576c;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
}

#box {
    width: 80%;
    background-color: #D5C6EE;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 20px;
    box-shadow: 0px 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    height: auto;
    
}

#title {
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#underline {
    border: none;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: #131E62;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#content {
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: justify;
    line-height: 1.6;
    flex-grow: 1;
}

.button {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

#know-more-button {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #AABFEF;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-size: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;

}

#know-more-button:hover {
    background-color: #0056b3;
}

body {
    background-image: url("https://c.wallhere.com/photos/c6/5c/chemistry_science_laboratories-1697571.jpg!d"); 
    background-size: cover; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
    background-position: center; 
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0; 
}
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Chem project</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="box">
        <h1 id="title">Brief Introduction</h1>
        <hr id="underline">
        <div id="content">
            <p>content</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div id="button-container" class="button">
        <a id="know-more-button" href="secondpage.html">Know More</a>
    </div>

</body>
</html>



Everything turns out to be good, except for the "know more button" that I expected to be in the bottom of the box. (shown below)

I would like to ask for your help in order to make the button appear at the right place. :)

If the answer helped solve your problem you can mark it as solved using the grey tick on the left of the answer.

The div of your button is not nested inside the box div. This means it will appear outside of the box.
It should look something like this:
    <div id="box">
        <h1 id="title">Brief Introduction</h1>
        <hr id="underline">
        <div id="content">
            <p>content</p>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div id="button-container" class="button">
            <a id="know-more-button" href="secondpage.html">Know More</a>
        </div>
    </div>

